# Use XAMPP-phpmyadmin database of windows in Linux XAMPP

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I was on `windows` and using `XAMPP`(installed somewhere else than C:/ )
Now i have moved on to `LINUX` and installed `LAMPP`.
So, i have this XAMPP folder from windows and i copied the project files from htdocs and now i need the database which i didn't exported while i was on windows.

I tried to copy the `phpmyadmin` folder from the old `XAMPP` folder but couldn't get it to work.

So how can i access the previous OS `phpmyadmin` to use my existing databases -

```
using linux (MINT - rosa-cinnamon)
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: MySQL data are never saved in the phpMyAdmin directory but in the MySQL data directory. As long as you don't have a backup of this directory you can't restore any database.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP to allow you to manipulate a MYSQL database. The location of the actual database will be in `\xampp\mysql\data` but its actual location and files used in the database will depend upon whether the database was MYISAM or INNODB

Comment: Thanks KittMedia  & RiggsFolly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move databases between hosts - especially when there are differences in the MySQL daemon version, operating systems (-versions) or storage schema - you should create a MySQL dump at host A and import it on host B: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

If this is no option for you anymore, you can try to move the old MySQL data directory (Configured in `my.ini` on windows, somewhere in the xampp directory) to the location where the new MySQL daemon stores its data files (Normally configured at `/etc/mysql.my.cnf`). A few more hints on this:

- Ensure to modify the file permissions on the data files at the new location that the MySQL daemon can work with them.
- On Windows, MySQL table names are case insensitive. On Linux they are case sensitive. Keep that in mind, if your application complains about missing tables.
- And of course: Test this with backups only!

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Maier